# Trouble with installing PyDev with Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I am trying to install the PyDev 3.2 plugin for Ecplise, but everytime I run the install, I get the following error:

> "Installing Software" has encountered a problem. An error occurred
>   while collecting items to be installed
>
> Details: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.2.0.201312292215. Error reading signed
>   content:/tmp/signatureFile6646901265687886222.jar An error occurred
>   while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6646901265687886222.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8322218222344706204.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile8322218222344706204.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4187876602334151122.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile4187876602334151122.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile840461721745061470.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile840461721745061470.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5939716086787202212.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5939716086787202212.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5983502155453326050.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5983502155453326050.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile600668738412712747.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile600668738412712747.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6189606464558584760.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6189606464558584760.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6135779137355138711.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6135779137355138711.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2057323306953091956.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2057323306953091956.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3794762954725200474.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile3794762954725200474.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4700622517373608280.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile4700622517373608280.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4649080137514243742.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile4649080137514243742.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.2.0.201312292215. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7141789939237504108.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile7141789939237504108.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile999992598312145305.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile999992598312145305.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2339395630123873267.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2339395630123873267.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5389215905872460392.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5389215905872460392.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2299502152167212708.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2299502152167212708.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5902210021605760235.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5902210021605760235.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.2.0.201312292215.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1585283163601835907.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile1585283163601835907.jar

Ubuntu Version: 12.04.4 LTS

Eclipse Platform: 3.7.2 (downloaded through software center)

PyDev Version: 3.2

I have tried various solutions, including unzipping and installation through the command prompt. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case you don't specifically need PyDev 3.2 : On the installation dialog, uncheck the box "Show only the latest versions of available software" and select the PyDev 2.8.2 version, which properly installed. I previously tried 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2, all failed.

I have the same config (Ubuntu 12.04 and Eclipse 3.7).

Answer (score 0):

Because I also had problems installing PyDev under eclipse, I tried the solution given by jmclem, but it didn't work. Although I unckecked the box "Show only the latest version of available software", only the last version was shown.
But then I tried this new URL and finally it worked:
http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml